# will_paginate -error-undefined method `total_pages'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I am using will_paginate "2.3.15" for my rails app

in my units_controller.rb

```
def index
    @units = Unit.paginate(:all ,:page => params[:page], :order => 'created_at DESC')
end

in my views(index)

        <%= will_paginate(@units)%>

but it gives error

undefined method `total_pages' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0xb523dc>
```

my rails version 3.0.0
 and ruby version 1.8.7

plz help

Answer (score 4):

Why do you add the `:all` ?
From the [will_paginate wiki](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki) you should probably use :

```
@units = Unit.paginate(:page => params[:page], :order => 'created_at DESC')
```

Comment: Thanks Adrien for your quick response i use this @units = Unit.paginate(:page => params[:page], :order => 'created_at DESC') still getting same error

Comment: I would think to a bug in this version of will_paginate but I'm not sure about that. Maybe you can try to update to a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

This occurred for me when the selected set size was zero.  (ie. in this case, @units.size == 0) Testing for it in the view seemed to solve the problem.  ie.

```
<% if @units.size > 0 %>
  <%= will_paginate @units %>
<% end %>
```