# undefined method `total_pages'- When use load_and_authorize_resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, authorization, cancancan

Am using cancancan for authorization.And am using will_paginate for table pagination. Its works fine until I add load_and_authorize_resource in controller. When using load_and_authorize_resource in controller, will_paginate throws `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method`total_pages' for #)`:
Abilyty.rb:

```
def initialize(user)    
    if user.user_type == "ADMIN" then
      can :manage, :all
      cannot :manage, ParentMessageController
    elsif user.user_type == "MANAGEMENT" then
      can :manage, :all
      cannot :manage, ParentAttendance
end
```

Controller:

```
class AssignmentsController < ApplicationController  
  before_action :set_assignment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  load_and_authorize_resource
def index
 getAssignments
end

def getAssignments
@assignments = Assignment.all
if (@assignments != nil && @assignments.length > 0) then                                                           
     @assignments = @assignments.paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
    end
  end
```

View:

```
<% if @assignments != nil then%>
    <%= will_paginate @assignments, :class => @paginationClass.to_s,  renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
    <%end%>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [will\_paginate -error-undefined method \`total\_pages'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356062/will-paginate-error-undefined-method-total-pages)

Answer (score 0):

This error appear when your @assignments is empty because in this case your code doesn't call `paginate` method. So, you should call pagination method always to avoid this problem (in your case just remove this useless `if`).

Comment: After I remove if conditions and call paginate method always but still throws same error@lsabel Stracke

Answer (score 0):

Change the object name used for pagination .

```
def getAssignments
@assignments = Assignment.all
if (@assignments != nil && @assignments.length > 0) then                                                           
     @assignment = @assignments.paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
    end
  end
```

and in your view like this

```
<% if @assignment != nil then%>
    <%= will_paginate @assignment, :class => @paginationClass.to_s,  renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
    <%end%>
```

This will fix your issue